# ms-access query for not trained

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I  have 2 query that will give me a list of employees not trained but I need to update it as once the employee is retrained we need to keep the old record so have created an inactive field for the record but I can`t figure out how to get the 2 queries I have setup to exclude the search in the modules tables so I have these tables

`EmployeeT - Primary Key EmployeeID` Holds employee information
`ModulesT - Primary Key ModuleID` Holds the employee training information
(this table has the inactive columns (Mod_Inactive datatype )
`SkillT - Primary Key SkillID` Holds the skill information for the modules

These are my 2 query that i use if the emploee has never been trained in a skill set

AllTraining Query

```
SELECT EmployeeT.EENumber, SkillT.SkillID 
FROM EmployeeT, SkillT GROUP
BY EmployeeT.EENumber, SkillT.SkillID;
```

NotTrained Query

```
SELECT EmployeeT.EENumber, [EmployeeT]![FirstName] & " " & [EmployeeT]![LastName] AS Employee, ContractT.Contract, ShiftT.Shift, SkillT.Description, ShiftT.ShiftID, ContractT.ContractID, SkillT.SkillID, EmployeeT.Inactive
FROM ShiftT INNER JOIN (ContractT INNER JOIN (((AllTrainings INNER JOIN EmployeeT ON AllTrainings.EENumber = EmployeeT.EENumber) INNER JOIN SkillT ON AllTrainings.SkillID = SkillT.SkillID) LEFT JOIN ModulesT ON (AllTrainings.SkillID = ModulesT.SkillID) AND (AllTrainings.EENumber = ModulesT.EENumber)) ON ContractT.ContractID = EmployeeT.ContractID) ON ShiftT.ShiftID = EmployeeT.ShiftID
WHERE (((EmployeeT.Inactive)=False) AND ((ModulesT.TestDate) Is Null))
ORDER BY EmployeeT.EENumber;
```

Simplyfied above query (i can now see i am not asking for anything from the modulesT table)

```
SELECT [EmployeeT]![FirstName] & " " & [EmployeeT]![LastName] AS Employee, SkillT.Description
    FROM (AllTrainings INNER JOIN EmployeeT ON AllTrainings.EENumber = EmployeeT.EENumber) INNER JOIN SkillT ON AllTrainings.SkillID = SkillT.SkillID
    ORDER BY EmployeeT.EENumber;
```

I know I am probably approaching this wrong and think I need to use some form of a sub query I have done lots of research on how sub query works put can’t seem to work them out any help on this is much appreciated I have been trying to work this out for weeks

So in short I need the all training query not to look at employees module if it is inactive.

Hope I make some sense grammar is not my strong suit.

I am working on this in ms-access 2010 have a front end & back-end database.

[Relationship Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlCy4.jpg)

UPDATE: 07/08/16

This Query give me a list of employees never had any training

```
SELECT A.EENumber, A.FirstName, A.LastName
FROM EmployeeT AS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (

SELECT *
FROM ModulesT AS B
WHERE A.EENUmber = B.EENumber

);
```

cant work out how to get a list from `SkillT` not in `ModulesT`

the end result i am looking for is something like this

```
    Name         Description
   Joe Bloggs   Some Skill 
   Joe Bloggs   Some Other SKill
   Phil Blank   Some Other Skill 
   Phil Blank   Some SKill
```

Comment: Describe the relation between these tables. Do ModulesT is filled for all employee with Mod_Inactive =false  and then you track these information.  what is ShiftT ,ContractT in second query.

Comment: I have put a picture of the relationship window in the first post. As i think it might be easier to see what I am doing wrong with my query but the ShiftT and ContractT are for the EmployeeT the SkillT holds all the information about what the module is how long before it expires in the ModuleT that holds when the Employee was trained who trained them  ect

Comment: Simplify the second query, it seems you get what is auto generated from the tool. You need not to include all tables in the query , bez the relation is represented by foreign key in the other table, plus you use table named AllTrainings which is not in the model, plus you use cascaded join. it is hard to be reviewed.

Comment: you can format the new query to let every join in one line , give alias name for tables. It's a good habit.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the new query to let every join in one line, give alias name   for tables.

It's a good habit,  and the formatting of sql represent visual relation between tables.

```
SELECT e![FirstName] & " " & e![LastName] AS Employee, 
       s.Description
FROM AllTrainings  a
INNER JOIN EmployeeT e ON a.EENumber = e.EENumber
INNER JOIN SkillT s ON a.SkillID = s.SkillID
where 
   -- add your creteria to filter data
ORDER BY e.EENumber
```

**EDit:**

If the field "ModulesT.Mod_Inactive" represent if the employee is trained ( 0 not trained , 1 trained)
so non trained employee and the corresponding Modules are:

```
 select EENumber ,ModulesID, SkillID
 from ModulesT 
 where
   Mod_Inactive = 0
```

note: You need not grouping
       you can join with the related tables to get extra columns

**Sugession:**

- The relation between EmployeeT and ModuleesT  is 1 to many
  So , primary key of ModulesT is composite key:EENumber ,ModulesID
- if the employee have more than ModuleeT and ModulesT may be assigned to more than Employee, so relation is many to many and you need third table to represent the intersection table

  so add Table, e.g, ModuleCatalog

  ModuleID 
  SkillID
  ModuleName

  ModuleCatalog  1->many with skillT 
  ModuleCatalog  1->many with ModulesT

you need to modify the relations in the model to reflect this new table.

**Edit 2:**

Q: How to get a list from SkillT not in ModulesT

A: Use left join skillT with ModulesT as:

```
SELECT s.Description, m.EEnumber
FROM skillT sLEFT
LEFT JOIN ModulesT m ON s.skillId = m.skilliD
WHERE m.skilliD Is Null
```

**Edit 3:**

The table ModulesT may contain more than one skill to the same employee and also more than one employee for the same skill, So you may create composite unique index on both EENumber and SkillId.

To create unique Index review: [create unique Index](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/composite-unique-index-access.html)

Comment: what I am trying to do is get a list of employees not trained which the above 2 queries give me but if they have a record in the modulesT and is inactive to add that into the Alltrainings Query I know I am not explaining this very well thank you for the advice on alias I am still learning and this has been a big learning curve for me

Comment: The query  AllTrainings  is not valid because it generate what is called cartezian product bez no join exist. Simply you need employe in modultT (who is emploee has never been trained in a skill) ,

Comment: ok have seen what you have said i thought my ModulesT was my intersection table between the employee & the SkillT i have been playing with the WHERE NOT EXSITS statement and with your comment about alias things have managed to get a list of employees not trained so half way there still trying to work out how to get a list of employess not trained in which skill i will add the working query to my question above if i still need another table i will look into that thanks for the help so far

Comment: I update my post to get list of employess not trained in which skill. You can join this query with EmployTT to get firstName +" " + lastname.

Comment: Been trying to get the above to work the last query you gave me gives me the list of skills but has no EENumber I can`t work out how to modify the above query to give me a list of all employees who has not been trained in a skill set as in modules table is null against the skillT so pop up joe as never been trained

Comment: I need to fix this point initially. I found ModulesT primary key is one field,, and the table is  intersection for 4 tables including EmployeeT. Is ModulesId auto increment? why not FK fields not part of PK.

Comment: i might of setup the design wrong first time i have setup any relationship database so everything has been trial and error. I have the database live but only got about 500 records so can be changed, ModulesT is  an Auto increment Feild i have setup a test database with just the 3 tables EmployeeT ModulesT and SkillT setup the same as the main  database with dummy records  i am open to a redesign if nessasery as i want the database to function currectly they can be duplicate records in the modulesT so when the Skill Expires i make the module inactive and setup the skill again

Comment: you should create unique index on both EEnumber, SkillID to avoid duplication. so you assign multi skills for employee. Is it match your business rules.

Comment: Yes i can create uniq index for the EENumber but the eenumber is a clock card number & will never be assigned to any indivdual more then once so will always be a uniq number the SkillT SkillID is a auto increment feild so the Skillid is uniq also not so much businiess rules but they dont want to remove any details of an employee they will want to get historical data for any employee i did try to move them to an archive table. but i have pdf attachments attached to the moduleID and was akward to move the attachments back the pdf are just links to the file locations on the work servers.

Comment: I mean composite  unique index on both fields  , not every field.

Comment: EENumber in employeeT will always be uniq and SkillT SkillID is uniq auto increment feild is that what you need to know

Comment: i can assign an auto incrment feild to employeeT if that is best practise for database design as i want to do best practise where ever possible. And thank you for all your time you have but into this really appreciate all your help.

Comment: ModulesT may contain more than skill to the same employee and also  more than employee for the same skill.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.EENumber, T.FirstName, T.LastName, T.Description
FROM (SELECT EENumber, FirstName, LastName, SKillID, Description FROM EmployeeT, SkillT)  
AS T LEFT JOIN ModulesT AS M ON (T.SkillID = M.SkillID) AND (T.EENumber = M.EENumber)
WHERE M.SkillID Is Null OR M.Mod_Inactive=True
ORDER BY T.EENumber, T.Description;
```

Have managed to get it working this now produces a list of employees who are not trained in a skill set and if the mod.inactive is set to true will show that module as needs training